# Using a classes within multiple namespaces across multiple files in C++

Tags: c++, avr-gcc

I'm having a problem compiling the following code with `avr-g++` (C++ compiler for AVR micro-controllers).

```
#ifndef SPI_H_
#define SPI_H_


#include "../LIBcpp.hpp"
namespace uC
{
    namespace SPI
    {
        class Device
        {
        private:
            SPI* m_SPI;
            uC::IO::Pin* m_CSPin;
            ChipSelectPolarity m_CSPolarity;

        public:
            Device(SPI& _SPI, uC::IO::Pin& _CSPin, ChipSelectPolarity _CSPolarity);

            void Select();
            void DeSelect();

            void WriteByte(uint8_t _Data);
            uint8_t WriteReadByte(uint8_t _Data);

            void WriteBytes(uint8_t _Data[], uint8_t _DataLength);
            void WriteReadBytes(uint8_t _Data[], uint8_t _ReadBuffer[], uint8_t _DataLength);
        };
    }
}


#endif /* SPI_H_ */
```

Note that I have defined several enumerations and classes within this file that are used in this class but have not been included to prevent the code from being too long.

I receive the errors

```
'IO' in namespace 'uC' does not name a type
'uC::IO' has not been declared
 expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
```

In my project, I have several files that represent specific `modules` of the project that I am working on. These files are in a sub-directory named `Modules`. The header file `LIBcpp.hpp` is in the directory above that. It includes the all of the header files within the `Modules` sub-directory.

The class `Pin` is defined within the namespace `IO`, which is within the namespace `uC`. This class is defined in a header file named `IO.hpp`, which is included by `LIBcpp.hpp`.

What I have tried:

Including the `IO.hpp` header file in the `SPI.hpp` header file - resulting in the same errors

I am at a loss as to how to solve this error. If more code or information is required to solve this problem, I will provide it.

Thanks!

This is `IO.hpp`, as requested:

```
#ifndef IO_H_
#define IO_H_


#include "../LIBcpp.hpp"

namespace uC
{
    namespace IO
    {
        class Port
        {
                //Contents removed
        };

        class Pin
        {
                //Contents removed
        };
    }
}


#endif /* IO_H_ */
```

Comment: Can you show us the IO.hpp file?

Comment: As you don't show the contents of the other files it is hard to say what the problem is. Either you did something wrong or you have a bug in your compiler. Some things to try: 1. Make certain all braces are balanced in all your header files. 2. Make certain all include statements are outside namespace blocks. 3 Try to make a minimal compilable example that illustrates the problem leaving out any irrelevant details like method signatures and post it here.

Comment: I've added the "IO.hpp" file and am working on creating a separate example that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The class "Pin" is defined within the namespace "IO", which is within
>   the namespace "uC". This class is defined in a header file named
>   "IO.hpp", which is included by "LIBcpp.hpp".

But `IO.hpp` includes `LIBcpp.hpp`. You have circular inclusions- this is extremely bad. You must alter your header structure so that there are no circular inclusions.

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware of the problems that could be caused by that header structure. I'll be sure to avoid that in the future!